# Microsoft edge extension to get the list of all installed extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, microsoft-edge-extension

I am creating edge browser extension. Basically I want to disable the other installed extension, I have a code which is working on chrome extension:

```
chrome.management.getAll(function (extensionInfo) {
    idExtensionEnabled = [];
    for (let i in extensionInfo) {
        if (extensionInfo[i].enabled && extensionInfo[i].name !== "xxxxx") { 
            idExtensionEnabled.push(extensionInfo[i].id);
            chrome.management.setEnabled(extensionInfo[i].id, false);
        }
    }
});
```

I want to make it compatible to edge

then I have searched for edge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getAll

But this is not working.

Your help is very appreciated, thank you

Comment: According to your link, Edge only has partial support. Also, please define what "not working" means...

Comment: later this year edge will release with webkit as basis and will also support all chrome extensions. so it won't work right now but in the near future.

Comment: Thanks @LeeTaylor This is my chrome code, which is working

chrome.management.getAll(function (extensionInfo) {
              //  console.log(extensionInfo);
                idExtensionEnabled = [];
                for (let i in extensionInfo) {
                    if (extensionInfo[i].enabled && extensionInfo[i].name !== "xxxxx") {
                        idExtensionEnabled.push(extensionInfo[i].id);
                        chrome.management.setEnabled(extensionInfo[i].id, false);
                    }
                }
            });
I want to make it compatible to edge.

Comment: @dev Please edit your question and make your changes there...

Comment: Okay thanks @cloned

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft Edge Extension support API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis), we can see that it doesn't support the function to manage the Microsoft Edge Extension.

And the management API is under consideration, more detail information, you could check the [Microsoft Edge extension API roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap).